# How to delete orphaned properties

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

At Special:Properties redlinks show up for properties that are referenced by deleted pages. Basically the question is the same as in:
http://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/31901925/

How do I get rid of such useless properties that make no sense since they are only referenced in deleted pages ...?

See https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/1402

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/31914096/) on the same site you referenced. It looks promising, however, I can't for the life of me get it to work. I would also like to delete unused properties.

**EDIT:**

Apologies for not including the answer. Please see below.

The suggestion was to delete `SMW_setup.php` and then re-setup.

```
php SMW_setup.php --delete
php SMW_setup.php
SMW_refreshData.php
```

This, however, did not work for me. Maybe it will work for you.
I have also tried combining the above with:

```
php setupStore.php --delete
php setupStore.php
php rebuildData.php -v
touch LocalSettings.php
```

Comment: I changed my question and added an issue at the SMW site. The above question will now be visible to the people following that issue via the link here.

Answer (score -1):

To remove an orphaned property create a page for the property and then delete the page.

Comment: Why on earth do you downvote my answer when the suggested solution works with current versions of MediaWiki and Semantic MediaWiki? You didn't mention in your question that you don't want to keep your software up-to-date. MediaWiki is currently at version 1.28 and Semantic MediaWiki at 2.4.4.

Comment: my question is from 2015 ... at that time MW1.23 SMW 2.2.2 was my setup was the setup and it still is. It's not about "wanting to keep software up to date" - i just don't do it if there is no necessity and won't do it just to check a Stackoverflow answer  -  you might want to edit your answer and say that the new version is  a prerequisite. Than it's a pretty good answer and might even solve my problem some time int the future when I decide to upgrade (I won't just to get rid of the orphans ...)

Comment: You have NOT specified in your question that the solution you asked for was for a specific version of the products. You are at fault.

Comment: Of course who is at fault is the main discussion topic on stackoverflow :-)